# Nullpointer Exception when assigning value to Integer array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

This seems a bit strange to me. I created a static Integer array and then I am trying to assign a value to it. But I get a Null pointer exception at the `degree[i] = 0` line.

Since I am not reading the value before assigning it, I do not understand why the NullPointer exception.

```
private static Integer[] degree;
public static void initDegree(int num_of_vertices) throws Exception{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_vertices; i++) {
        degree[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have not initialized the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array.

ex

```
degree = new Integer[5];
```

Otherwise, the array itself is just a null.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I initialize it if I do not know the size beforehand?

Comment: @Yathi use `ArrayList`

Comment: @Yathi or initialize it before `for` loop, like: `degree = new Integer[num_of_vertices]; `